# why does golang nil pointer dereference happen in submethods

Tags: go, segmentation-fault

I have this code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    Bar string
}

func (f *Foo) level4() {
    fmt.Printf("Bar = %s\n", f.Bar)
}

func (f *Foo) level3() {
    f.level4() // panics here, 2 levels down
}

func (f *Foo) level2() {
    f.level3()
}

func (f *Foo) level1() {
    f.level2()
}

type FooWrapper struct {
    foo *Foo
}

func main() {
    w := FooWrapper{}
    w.foo.level1() // expected it to panic here, since foo is nil
}
```

As expected, running this gives

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x47f454]
```

However, I expected the nil pointer dereference to happen at `w.foo.level1()`, since `foo` is `nil`. Instead, it calls levels 1, 2 and 3 and panics there. Why is this the case?

[playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/wDgekH9nLQ0)

Comment: Go methods are essentially syntactic sugar.  `func (f *Foo) level1()` is functionally equivalent to `func level1(*Foo)`   Therefore, calling a pointer receiver on a `nil` pointer is perfectly valid, and *calling a method does not dereference a pointer receiver*.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. If it wasn't a comment I would have marked this as the accepted answer, since it does answer my question. However, I still don't get why it panics at `f.level4()` and not at `fmt.Printf("Bar = %s\n", f.Bar)` then

Comment: It panics within `level4` before `Printf` is called, when it tries to determin the value `f.Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Why is this the case?

Because  w.foo.level1() is valid statement and similarly  f.level2(),  f.level3(),  f.level4() are also a valid statement.

try this

```
func (f *Foo) level1() {
    println("Hello Go")
    f.level2()
}
```

it will print `Hello Go` and call `f.level2()` and also see last call level 4

```
func (f *Foo) level4() {
    println("Hello Go 4")
    fmt.Printf("Bar = %s\n", f.Bar) 
}
```

it will print `Hello Go 4` but panic on next line it is showing the trace or you can say origin of error

Answer (score 0):

The default value of any pointer type is `nil`.

As you are constructing your object using

```
w := FooWrapper{}
```

The value of `foo` will be assigned the default `nil`.

To resolve the problem you should pass a value for `foo`.

```
w := FooWrapper{foo: &Foo{Bar: "bar"}}
```

What I usually do to prevent this issue is to make some constructor function.

```golang
func NewFooWrapper() *FooWrapper {
   return &FooWrapper{foo: &Foo{Bar: "bar"}}
}

w := NewFooWrapper()
```

Or in case the value of `foo` can't be hardcoded.

```golang
func NewFooWrapper(foo *Foo) *FooWrapper {
   return &FooWrapper{foo: foo}
}

w := NewFooWrapper(&Foo{Bar: "bar"})
```

This makes it more explicit from a coding point of view preventing these errors in other places of code.

Answer (score -1):

You did not initialize the `FooWrapper` in your main function correctly. Your `foo` field with type `*Foo` is `nil` inside `w` variable type of `FooWrapper` because you have not assigned a value for that and the default value for a pointer type variable is `nil` in Go

Simple correct initialization as follows

```
    w := FooWrapper{
        foo: &Foo{
            Bar: "bar",
        },
    }
```

run in [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Vx-GYZ_NBSy)

output :

```
Bar = bar
```

The reason that panic doesn't come in `level1()`, `level2()`, `level3()` is because they are not using any `Foo`'s fields inside those functions. And also in `level4()` panic occurs not because of the function call, but because it's using `f.Bar` in print.

In Go,

> If the concrete value inside the interface itself is nil, the method will be called with a nil receiver.

You can find a simple example for this in https://go.dev/tour/methods/12

And also you can find a great explanation for this in Go specs documentation under [Calls](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls)

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()

Comment: not initializing the foo variable was intended. As I said in the question, I wanted to see at which point it will panic. It did not panic in level4, but in level3.

Comment: I think you didn't get the answer correct. It panics at `level4()`. But panic trace shows as `level3()` because there is no other thing in the `level4()` function. If you add some simple print inside `level4()` before `printf`, you can see the actual panic.

Comment: If you are using IDE with debugging functionality, Please do debug step by step and you can see where exactly panic happens.